# Align the border of a polygon to overlap the border of another using QGis

Tags: qgis, alignment

[image]
I have two polygon layers. As seen in picture, the border of two layers do not fit. I want to align the border of layer 1 (blue) to overlap the border of layers 2 (pink). How to do it with QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to copy the feature from the pink layer to the blue layer. If you're looking into a more elaborate method, you could do the following:

1. Intersect the 2 layers. `Vector > Geoprocessing tools > Intersection`
2. Calculate the difference between the 2 layers: `Vector > Geoprocessing tools > Difference`
3. Union the intersection and the difference: `Vector > Geoprocessing tools > Union`
4. Merge the features using Union from the advanced digitising toolbar.